# Nagios notifications definitions

Tags: nagios, sms

I am trying to monitor a web server in such a way that I want to search for a particular string on a page via http. The command is defined in command.cfg as follows

```
# 'check_http-mysite command definition'
define command {
        command_name check_http-mysite
        command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H mysite.example.com -s "Some text" }

# 'notify-host-by-sms' command definition
define command {
        command_name  notify-host-by-sms 
        command_line  /usr/bin/send_sms $CONTACTPAGER$ "Nagios - $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ :Host$HOSTALIAS$ is $HOSTSTATE$ ($OUTPUT$)"
}
# 'notify-service-by-sms' command definition
define command {
        command_name  notify-service-by-sms 
        command_line  /usr/bin/send_sms $CONTACTPAGER$ "Nagios - $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ ($OUTPUT$)"
}
```

Now if nagios doesn't find "Some text" on the home page mysite.example.com, nagios should notify a contact via sms through the Clickatell http API which I have a script for that that I have tested and found that it works fine.

Whenever I change the command definition to search for a string which is not on the page, and restart nagios, I can see on the web interface that the string was not found. What I don't understand is why isn't the notification sent though I have defined the host, hostgroup, contact, contactgroup and service and so forth. What I'm I missing, these are my definitions, In my web access through the cgi I can see that I have notifications have been defined and enabled though I don't get both email and sms notifications during hard status changes.

*host.cfg*

```
define host {
        use                     generic-host
        host_name               HAL
        alias                   IBM-1
        address                 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        check_command           check_http-mysite     
}
```

*hostgroups_nagios2.cfg*

```
# my website
define hostgroup{
       hostgroup_name  my-servers
       alias           All My Servers
       members         HAL 
}
```

*contacts_nagios2.cfg*

```
define contact {
        contact_name                    colin   
        alias                           Colin Y
        service_notification_period     24x7
        host_notification_period        24x7
        service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s
        host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
        service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email,notify-service-by-sms
        host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email,notify-host-by-sms
        email                           myaccount@mysite.com
        pager                           +254xxxxxxxxx
}

define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name   site_admin 
        alias               Site Administrator
        members             colin 
}
```

*services_nagios2.cfg*

```
# check for particular string in page via http 
define service {
        hostgroup_name                  my-servers
        service_description             STRING CHECK
        check_command                   check_http-mysite
        use                             generic-service
        notification_interval           0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
        contacts                        colin
        contact_groups                  site_admin
}
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Here are the generic-host and generic-service definitions

*generic-service_nagios2.cfg*

```
# generic service template definition
define service{
        name                            generic-service ; The 'name' of this service template
        active_checks_enabled           1       ; Active service checks are enabled
        passive_checks_enabled          1       ; Passive service checks are enabled/accepted
        parallelize_check               1       ; Active service checks should be parallelized (disabling this can lead to major performance problems)
        obsess_over_service             1       ; We should obsess over this service (if necessary)
        check_freshness                 0       ; Default is to NOT check service 'freshness'
        notifications_enabled           1       ; Service notifications are enabled
        event_handler_enabled           1       ; Service event handler is enabled
        flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
        failure_prediction_enabled      1       ; Failure prediction is enabled
        process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
        retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
        retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
                notification_interval           0               ; Only send notifications on status change by default.
                is_volatile                     0
                check_period                    24x7
                normal_check_interval           5
                retry_check_interval            1
                max_check_attempts              4
                notification_period             24x7
                notification_options            w,u,c,r
                contact_groups                  site_admin
        register                        0       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL SERVICE, JUST A TEMPLATE!
}
```

*generic-host_nagios2.cfg*

```
define host{
        name                            generic-host    ; The name of this host template
        notifications_enabled           1       ; Host notifications are enabled
        event_handler_enabled           1       ; Host event handler is enabled
        flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
        failure_prediction_enabled      1       ; Failure prediction is enabled
        process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
        retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
        retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
                max_check_attempts              10
                notification_interval           0
                notification_period             24x7
                notification_options            d,u,r
                contact_groups                  site_admin 
        register                        1       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL HOST, JUST A TEMPLATE!
}
```

Comment: Where are your generic-host and generic-service defs?  They might be kinda important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, actually the configurations were ok, the problem was nagios executes the SMS script as the user 'nagios' which doesn't have permissions to write to the log files in /tmp/. But this is not explained in any of the blogs I read on setting up nagios notifications via SMS. I sort of had to find out by myself, almost made my head explode.